# How can I add columns with same first column in Excel?

Tags: excel, group-by, reporting, excel-formula

I have a large reporting table in Excel that looks similar to the following.  I need to add all the numbers for each name and average all the percentages.

```
Name    Number    Percent
-------------------------
Alan    1         20%
Barb    2         20%
Corey   3         40%
Barb    1         30%
Alan    2         20%
Daniel  3         80%
Alan    1         10%
```

I'm looking for:

```
Name    Number    Percent
-------------------------
Alan    4         17%
Barb    3         25%
Corey   3         40%
Daniel  3         80%
```

Sheet One will have the raw data and sheet two will have the summary.  How can I add one column ("Number") while grouping by another column ("Name")?  How would this function change to average the third column the same way?  (Not using VBA)

Comment: What is the longhand calculation? How do you get Alan = 43%?

Comment: Oops, edited. Dumb miscalculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want simple sums and averages over a "large" data set, a pivot table is by far the quickest solution.

Looking at your sample results, however, I suspect you really want a *weighted average* on `Percent` where `Number` is the weight (even though some of the sample results look squirrelly, but I am guessing this is because your sample results are representative of a larger data set). This can be done quickly with pivot tables as well, using a helper column in the data table.

- Add a new column in the data sheet called `ExtPercent` where the calculation is Number * Percent
- Create the pivot table to include the new column in the source data
- Place `Name` in the row area
- Add a calculated field to the PT called "Weighted Average Percent"
  with formula `= ExtPercent / Percent` and add this to the data area
- You can, of course, add the sum of `Number` to the data area as well

Comment: Good call on the weighted average.  Average percentage is almost meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this just once (i.e. some manual intervention) or regular (i.e. [Array] formula or VBA)?

In order to identify the duplicates, I would use =countif(A$3:A$9,A3) in e.g. D3 and copy the formula down. for the ranking. If you want to identify only the first unique value, you could use =IF(COUNTIF(A3:A$9,A3)>1,”Duplicate”,”Unique"). I specifically removed the $ from the A3, so this formula uses a reduced lookup range when copied down.

I would use SumIf( range, criteria, sum_range ), to add the scores. So in this case =SumIf(A$3:A$9,A3, B$3:B$9).

If you want to create this condensed list with formulae, look over here.
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/